# Why am I getting 503 when deploying puppeteer app?

Tags: node.js, deployment, puppeteer, web-deployment, nodejs-server

I've deployed my puppeteer app on multiple web servers but getting the same error **503 service unavailable** on all of them when trying to access the puppeteer route.

I think the error is caused because the web servers are unable to handle express and puppeteer together.

When I access a route which has puppeteer code, the browser gets opened and the express request is exited.

I'm using the following args,

```
headless: true,
args: [
  `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
  `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
  "--no-sandbox",
],
```

Everything is working fine locally.

I've also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594840/puppeteer-gets-503-error-when-deployed-but-not-locally), but no luck.

Comment: have you figured out any solution for this? I'm having the same problems during deploying 

Comment: nope.. I had to buy a VPS and setup the app there..